# Manipulating the DOM using jQuery .resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, resize

I want to change the order of elements in the DOM based on different browser sizes.

I've looked into using `intention.js` but feel that it might be overkill for what I need (it depends on `underscore.js`).

So, i'm considering using jQuery's `.resize()`, but want to know if you think something like the following would be acceptable, and in line with best practices...

```
var layout = 'desktop';
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var ww = $( window ).width();
    if(ww<=767 && layout !== 'mobile'){
        layout = 'mobile';
        // Do something here
    }else if((ww>767 && ww<=1023) && layout !== 'tablet'){
        layout = 'tablet';
        // Do something here
    }else if(ww>1023 && layout !== 'desktop'){
        layout = 'desktop';
        // Do something here
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

I'm storing the current layout in the `layout` variable so as to only trigger the functions when the window enters the next breakpoint.

Comment: CSS media queries seem like a better choice, depending on what you're actually doing ?

Comment: I'm basically moving the left sidebar after the main content on mobiles, so it appears at the bottom of the screen rather than the top. Not sure this can be achieved with media queries alone?

Comment: I agree with adeneo, and I think that you should use media queries

Comment: It would be acceptable and **not** in line with best practices. Go with media queries and change `position` prop of sidebar in css. And pls add subjective tag :)

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are generally preferred. However, if I am in a situation where I am in a single page application that has a lot of manipulation during runtime, I will use onresize() instead. Javascript gives you a bit more freedom to work with dynamically setting breakpoints (especially if you are moving elements around inside the DOM tree with stuff like append()). The setup you have is pretty close to the one I use:

```
function setWidthBreakpoints(windowWidth) {
    if (windowWidth >= 1200) {
        newWinWidth = 'lg';
    } else if (windowWidth >= 992) {
        newWinWidth = 'md';
    } else if (windowWidth >= 768) {
        newWinWidth = 'sm';
    } else {
        newWinWidth = 'xs';
    }
}

window.onresize = function () {

    setWidthBreakpoints($(this).width());

    if (newWinWidth !== winWidth) {
        onSizeChange();
        winWidth = newWinWidth;
    }
};

function onSizeChange() {
// do some size changing events here.
}
```

The one thing that you have not included that is considered best practice is a [debouncing function](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/), such as the one below provided by Paul Irish, which prevents repeated firing of the resize event in a browser window:

```
(function($,sr){

  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null;
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
  }
  // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');


// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  // code that takes it easy...
});
```

So incorporate a debouncer into your resize function and you should be golden.

Comment: Thanks @Conor that's really helpful. Though i'm currently testing out a CSS-only approach using the flexbox model. Will report back!

Answer (score 0):

In the practice is better to use **Media Queries**

Comment: Sometimes if you change the media query during runtime it is a better idea to use javascript.

Comment: How can you use media queries to move elements around the DOM though? Say moving the left sidebar, which on desktops appears before the main content in the DOM, to appear after the main content on mobiles?

Comment: @pavsid You just change css display and position of sidebar and its neighbors. Invest you time in planing html and css structure and you won't have this problem.

Comment: @Drops Can you suggest some "proper" HTML and CSS structures that would overcome this problem?

Comment: @pavsid I'm not talking about something set in stone, but next time try developing for mobile first and you'll see how different it is. Like i said adjusting css `position: absolute/rel` and/or `display` on sidebar and its siblings will probably solve it. For more help ask another question or edit this one (give us your dumbed down html and css).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emrEvv), I'm in a hurry atm and will refactor later.

SCSS:

```
body, html, .wrapper { width: 100%; height: 100% }

.sidebar { width: 20%; height: 500px; float: left;      
  &.mobile { display: none } }  

.content { float: right; width: 80% }

.red { background-color: red }
.blue { background-color: blue }
.green { background-color: green }

@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
  .content { width: 100%; float: left }
  .sidebar { display: none 
    &.mobile { display: block; width: 100% }
  }
}
```

HAML

```
.wrapper
  .sidebar.blue
  .content.red
  .content.green
  .sidebar.mobile.blue
```

On 700 px page breaks, sidebar disappears and mobile sidebar appears.
This can be much more elegant but you get the picture.

Only possible downside to this approach is duplication of sidebar.

That's it, no JS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason for my original question was because I couldn't find a way to move a left sidebar (which appears first in the HTML) to appear *after* the content on mobiles.

Despite the comments, I still can't see how using media queries and `position` or `display` alone would reliably solve the problem (perhaps someone can give an example?).

But, it did lead me to investigate the flexbox model - `display: flex`, and so I have ended up using that, and specifically flex's `order` property to re-arrange the order of the sidebars and content area.

Good guide here - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/